# Secondary operations in $H^*P$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I would be very grateful for any answer to this or pointing at a reference.

Let $P$ be the infinite dimensional real projective space and $\Phi_{j,j}$ be the Adams operation based on the Adem relation for $Sq^{2^j}Sq^{2^j}$. I wonder what are the known examples of computing the action of these operations on $H^*P$. More specifically, I would like to know the action of this operation on $H^{2^{j+1}}P$. From the Hopf invariant one result, I can read off that the action of $\Phi_{j,j}$ for small values of $j$ is trivial. But, how can I understand the other ones?

Comment: Maybe try John Harper's book *Secondary Cohomology Operations* pg. 147 onwards. Especially Pr. 5.3.5.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for reminding of the book. I will take a look!

Comment: @Tyrone I like to add that the aforementioned Proposition in your comment is about evaluation of $\phi_{0,j}$. But, thanks for reminding of this and of the book.